# artifactory upload with checksum using powershell

Tags: artifactory

How would you upload an artifact using powershell?

The following works with bash

```
ARTIFACT_MD5_CHECKSUM=$(md5sum /tmp/bar.zip | awk '{print $1}')
ARTIFACT_SHA1_CHECKSUM=$(shasum -a 1 /tmp/bar.zip | awk '{ print $1 }') 

curl --upload-file "/tmp/bar.zip" --header "X-Checksum-MD5:${ARTIFACT_MD5_CHECKSUM}" --header "X-Checksum-Sha1:${ARTIFACT_SHA1_CHECKSUM}"  -u "admin:${ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY}" -v https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/foo/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Invoke-RestMethod`

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String '<api_key>'
$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ('admin', $password)

$ARTIFACT_SHA1_CHECKSUM=$(Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA1 c:\bar.zip).Hash
$HEADERS = @{"X-Checksum-SHA1"=$ARTIFACT_SHA1_CHECKSUM;};

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/foo/bar.zip -Method PUT -InFile c:\bar.zip -cred $cred -Headers $HEADERS
```

Including the SHA1 hash as part of the headers is optional.

Make sure:

- use 'PUT' not 'POST'
- filename must be part of the URI

Sha256 checksums [can't currently be uploaded](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-6962), instead their calculation needs to be [requested through the api.](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SetItemSHA256Checksum)

```
$CONTENT = @{"repoKey"="nd-web-zips";"path"=$localFile} | ConvertTo-Json
# For some reason, the api doesn't like $cred, pass the api key in directly to the headers
$HEADERS2 = @{"X-JFrog-Art-Api"=$APIKEY}
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/api/checksum/sha256 -Method POST -Body $CONTENT -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $HEADERS2
```